# For which input signals is the response resonant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, exponential-function

Consider the differential equation $y''' + 5y'' + 8y' + 6y = f(x)$.
For which following input signals $f(x)$ is the response resonant? Choose all those that apply.

$e^x, e^{-x}, e^{3x}, e^{-3x}, e^x\cos(x), e^{-x}\cos(x), e^x\sin(x), e^{-x}\sin(x), e^{-x}\sin(3x), e^{-3x}\sin(3x)$

Using the ERF formula, $z_p = e^{rt}/P(r)$ where $P(r) = r^3 + 5r^2 + 8r + 6$ and the system is in resonance if $P(r) = 0$. Clearly, $r=-3$ works and hence one of the answers if $e^{-3x}$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the choices that multiplies $e^{\omega x}$ with sinusoids.

Am I right in thinking that their P(r) equation stays the same and the input (r) can just be the coefficient of the exponent?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of $r^3 + 5r^2 + 8r + 6=0$ is $r=-3$, $r=-1\pm i$.

Then

$f(x)=e^{-x}\sin x$ or $f(x)=e^{-x}\cos x$